# PayPal Recurring Payments Item Purhcase

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I am developing a payment system using PayPal Recurring Payments (SOAP API).

I am Creating a Recurring Profile and setting up the monthly billing amt, period etc. Now when the user wants to upgrade his plan, I would like to Bill the buyer for the difference amount by using the same Credit card info which is associated with his recurring profile. How can we achieve this? Shall we do a complete separate transaction? Or DoReferenceTransaction API?

If I do a separate Transaction will PayPal allow me to do another transaction if the monthly recurring day falls in the next 72 hours?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go with reference transactions like you mentioned.  That would be separate from the profile, so yeah, if the recurring payment comes soon after it would process like normal.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, what I am looking for is to do the transaction without having the customer fill in the cc info again. Is there any way of achieving this? DoReferenceTransaction? using and earlier transaction id...

Comment: Yes, DoReferenceTransaction is how you would do it.